# Half of information uploaded, only images no data in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I created an app that at the same time sends data to a google sheet and image to a drive where the uploaded image URL is displayed alongside the data sent.
My issue is that the image is uploaded properly with the date and time in the title but my data aren't sent to the google script.

I tried but didn't found any workable solution.

here is my code

```
function doGet(e) {
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').getSheetByName("Test_Sheet");
  return addUser(e);
}

function doPost(e) {
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').getSheetByName("Test_Sheet");
  return addUser(e);
}

function addUser(e) {

  var tag1 = e.parameter.tag1;
  var tag2 = e.parameter.tag2;
  var nameTag = e.parameter.nameTag;
  var mimetypeTag = e.parameter.mimetypeTag;
  var dataTag = e.parameter.dataTag;
  var filename = nameTag + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(dataTag);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, mimetypeTag, filename);
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').createFile(blob).getID();

  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  var fileId = file.getId();

  var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + fileId;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16T_51Xtjm5udbYBAEfSbNpo--ox9PQZddT39Ty0Zky8').getSheetByName("Test_Sheet");
  sheet.appendRow([tag1, tag2, nameTag, mimetypeTag, dataTage, filename, fileUrl])

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data uploaded");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `dataTage` with `dataTag`.

Comment: replaced but issue still maintain

Comment: I am assuming that you are referring to the `sheet.appendRow()` call only pushing some of the data to the spreadsheet. What do you see after the code has run? What is your expected result? Does the execution log show any errors?

Comment: This was also asked on the App Inventor Community and answered here: https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/upload-files-to-gdrive-followed-by-a-link-of-the-uploaded-file-in-google-sheet/31591/6